# How to break an functional-style iteration?

Tags: javascript

I'm experimenting with functional-style Javascript and have encountered an interesting situation. I have a foreach function that takes a collection and function object:

```
var Utils = {};

// Applies a functor to each item in a collection.
Utils.foreach = function(collection, functor)
{
  for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++)
  {
    functor(collection[i]);
  }
};
```

This is cool. However now I want to implement another function:

```
// Checks if a collection contains an item.
Utils.has = function(collection, item)
{
    Utils.foreach(collection, function(obj) {
        if (item === obj) {
            return true; // How to force a return from the foreach function?
        }
    });
    return false;
};
```

As you can see I can't implement the "has" function because my return statement doesn't break the iteration.

Can someone recommend a solution for this problem?

Comment: You need to use a closure that captures a boolean flag variable to indicate whether it should further process items or not, and flip the flag as appropriate.

Comment: Just use `Array.some` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Comment: Check jQuery's 'each' method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you want is not actually `forEach`, but rather [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) (other languages call it `any`). The couterpart is [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) (or `all` in other languages). You'll find an example implementation on MDC.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something real quick and untested ( it is friday 4:50 time to go home). I'll try to test and update this post later. see if this helps:

```
Utils = {};
Utils.foreach = function(collection, functor) {
    loop: for (var i in collection) {
        if (functor(collection[i])) {
            alert("breaking the loop!");
            break loop;
        }
    }
};
Utils.has = function(collection, item) {
    var bolReturn  = false;
    Utils.foreach(collection, function(obj) {
        if (item === obj) {
            bolReturn = true;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
    return bolReturn;
};
Utils.has({"test":""}, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a modification to each.

Start by modifying `has`:

```
Utils.has = function (collection, item) {
  var found = false;
  Utils.foreach(collection, function (obj) {
    if (item === obj) {
      found = true;
      return false;
    }
  });
  return found;
};
```

Then you need to modify `forEach` to end early when it gets `false`

```
Utils.foreach = function (collection, functor) {
  var prop;
  for (prop in collection) {
    if (prop.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      if (functor(collection[prop]) === false) {
        return;
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to abandon your structure-
why not throw and catch an error to break out of the loop?

```
  Utils.has= function(collection, item){
    try{
        ControlCenter.foreach(collection, function(obj){
            if(item=== obj){
                throw 'found it!'
            }
        });
    }
    catch(er){
        if(er== 'found it!') return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```